# $x \in \mathrm{Span}(s\cup\{y\})$ and $y \not \in \mathrm{Span}(s\cup\{x\})$ then $x \in \mathrm{Span}(s)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to write out $x= \alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2+...+\alpha_nx_n$. Since $y$ is an element of $\mathrm{Span}(s\cup\{x\})$ how does this impact the problem. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Should I write out the rest of the spans as linear combinations?

Answer (score 0):

We will assume $s = \mathrm{Span}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Because $x \in \mathrm{Span}(s \cup \{y\})$ we can write,

$$x = \alpha_0 y + \alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_n x_n $$

Therefore,

$$ \alpha_0 y = x-(\alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_n x_n)$$

If $\alpha_0 \neq 0$ then we would have,

$$y = \dfrac{1}{\alpha_0}(x-(\alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_n x_n))$$

But $y \not \in \mathrm{Span}(s\cup \{x\})$ so that would be in contradiction.

Therefore $\alpha_0 = 0$ and finally,

$$x = \alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_n x_n$$

So $x \in \mathrm{Span}(s)$.